# Redirect from nested master page contruct a url with actual application folder instead of root

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, master-pages

I have a nested master page, used for the admin part of a website. When I redirect to a login page from that master page, the redirect construct a weird url. "_hosting" is the actual folder in which the application folder "applicationname" is. So instead of having this :

```
www.sitename.com/admin/login.aspx
```

I get this :

```
www.sitename.com/_hosting/applicationname/admin/login.aspx
```

I try redirecting using "~/admin/login.aspx", remove the "~" and ".." but nothing works. When the application is run localy, it doesnt do that, It redirect corrrectly to:

```
http://localhost:63820/admin/login.aspx
```

I don't understand what is causing this. From what Ive read, it has something to do with the nested master page but didnt find anything that helped me solve this.

My last option would be to remove the unwanted part of the path and redirect that way, but I would like to solve this the right way.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Page always redirect on right path as you tell that your login page path is

```
www.sitename.com/_hosting/applicationname/admin/login.aspx
```

For the redirect login page you used this path but you can reduce it make a public class where 
you take a constant variable and give here full path and use that constant variabe as redirect path

Comment: not sure if I understand exactly what you say, but using a constant variable is not the cleanest way of doing this. I'm trying to figure out a way to get the "_hosting/applicationame/" programatically, if I have to build the path myself. Relying on a constant is not the best option.  Also, even this method would be the last option, because finding the right way to redirect in case of nester master page would be the first thing i want.